# Magento 2.4.4 not loading theme files

Tags: theme, magento2.4

I just installed the `Magento 2.4.4` successfully and it's showing the website in the browser, but not loading the `js` and `css` files.

However, I set the root file to `pub` folder and updated the `.conf` file as below

[image]

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/connector/pub/
ServerName connector
ServerAlias connector
```

and also updated the `hosts` file

[image]

Still the website is not loading correctly.
[image]

getting error when opening the `css` files

[image]

if I remove the **version** it is showing

[image]

**Is there any configuration do I missed?** Can you please help me on this?

Comment: Disabling 'dev/static/sign' will temporarily fix your issue but not solve the problem. Are you using Apache or Nginx?

Comment: @MagePalExtensions Apache.

Comment: Check to see if mod_rewrite is enabled. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337724/how-to-check-whether-mod-rewrite-is-enable-on-server

Comment: Make sure pub/static.php exist... then try ``http://connector/static.php?resource=/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/css/print.css`` (see pub/static/.htaccess line #12)

Comment: @MagePalExtensions let me check

Comment: @MagePalExtensions, thank you for the reply, getting the error requested path `/frontend/Magento/luma/en_Us/css/print.css` is wrong. **Error** is `Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [pub/static.php:13]` Please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Followed the [Magento Dev Docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/tutorials/change-docroot-to-pub.html) steps, it's worked for me.

Please let me if any issues, if not worked.

Answer (score 1):

I have got same issue in nginx server, Still i am unable to find out exact issue.

I had figure out it with temperately solution.

change value of `dev/static/sign` to `0` form `core_config_data` table.

check with below update

> ```
> UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = '0' WHERE `path` = 'dev/static/sign';
> ```

after execute below commands.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f;
php bin/magento cache:clean;
```

and set proper permission.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, updated still not working.

Comment: is it version number there in url?

Comment: Yes, the version number exists in the URL.

Comment: Open your database. and serach "'dev/static/sign" in core_config_data.

Comment: if you find that value replace it with 0.

Comment: execute "php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f" and set permission for var pub and generated folder.

Check with private browser.

Comment: Tried your suggestions—still, no luck.

Answer (score 1):

please open your database, **core_config_data** table and then run following query into this.

```
insert into core_config_data (config_id, scope, scope_id, path, value) values (null, 'default', 0, 'dev/static/sign', 0);
```

After run the above query please run following command in your Magento root

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the following commands.

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
sudo chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, updated still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Use these command.
sudo chmod -R 777 var generated/ pub/static pub/media

sudo chmod -R 777 .